# Problem with calculating high frequency response of a CE amp

Tags: amplifier, bjt, high-frequency

I have this amp: [image]

The parameters of the transistor are hfe=120, Cje=40pF and Cjc=4pF. I am also told to assume Cpi = Cje = 40pF and Cmu = Cjc= 4 pF. 
From that I should calculate fh and compare it with the simulation.

[image]

Here's the output of the simulation. It shows -3db point around 2 MHz, which is according to the design constraints. However when I compute fh by hand I get completely different results. I use following reasoning:

fH = 1/2πCinR’sig

Cin=Cπ + Cµ(1+gmR’L) = 40pF + 4pF(1+0.06A/V*3680Ω) = 927 pF

R’L= ro||RC||RL = 3680 Ω

R’sig = rπ||(rπ + (RB||Rsig)) = 7300Ω

From this fh is about 23 kHz, which is way off. I have no idea where I am making a mistake. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Consider \$f\approx \frac{1}{2\pi\:C_\text{jc}\:\left[R_3\mid\mid R_2\mid\mid h_\text{fe}\cdot\left( R_5+R_6\right)\right]}\$

Answer (score 0):

Stage gain is approx. 40.

Cmiller is gain * Cob = 160pF.

Tau of Cmiller-loaded input LPF is 1Kohm * 160pF = 160nanoSecond, or 1MHz F3dB.